# Is there a way to make the queries on the Parse Server shorter?

Tags: javascript, database, object, parse-platform, parse-server

**Original Query**

```js
const Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post')
const queryPost = new Post()

queryPost.startsWith('title', 'Good Programming')
queryPost.greaterThan('totalLike', 1000)
queryPost.limit(100)
queryPost.include('author')

query.find()
```

**Expected Query**

```js
const Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post')
const queryPost = new Post()

queryPost.find({
   startsWith: {
      title: 'Good Programming'
   },
   greaterThan: {
      totalLike: 1000
   },
   include: ['post'],
   limit: 100
})
```

The advantage of the method above, I can do the copy and paste as usual when I want to do trials across places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following but it is not documented:

```js
const query = Parse.Query.fromJSON('ClassName', {
  where: {
    title: {
      '$regex': '^Good Programming'
    },
    totalLike: {
      '$gt': 1000
    }
  },
  include: 'post',
  limit: 100
});

query.find();
```

Comment: What about the `select` method? What is the implementation like?

Comment: You need to add one more key in the JSON similar to `include`, a string with the comma separated list of fields you want to select: `select: "field1,field2"`

Answer (score 0):

If you need a JSON version of the query, just run `toJSON` method to get formatted query as a JSON:

**Example**

```js
const Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post')
const queryPost = new Post()

queryPost.startsWith('title', 'Good Programming')
queryPost.greaterThan('totalLike', 1000)
queryPost.limit(100)
queryPost.include('author')
queryPost.select(['id', 'name'])

console.log(queryPost.toJSON())
```

**Output**

```js
{
  where: {
    title: {
      '$regex': '^\QGood Programming\E'
    },
    totalLike: {
      '$gt': 1000
    }
  },
  include: 'post',
  keys: 'id,name',
  limit: 100
}
```

and you can re-execute the above JSON Query using the `fromJSON` method.

**Example**

```js
const query = Parse.Query.fromJSON('ClassName', {
  where: {
    title: {
      '$regex': '^Good Programming'
    },
    totalLike: {
      '$gt': 1000
    }
  },
  include: 'post',
  keys: 'id,name',
  limit: 100
});

query.find();
```